# How to render a json string from bson document

Tags: json, mongodb, go, marshalling, bson

I am struggling to create a valid JSON string from a BSON document in Go for an API.
Let's say I have an object like this:

```
type MyObject struct {
    Name string
}
```

I call my database which returns to me a cursor containing many documents as: `[{"Name": "object_name"}, ...]`

I am able to retrieve all the documents via a loop like

```
for cur.Next(ctx) {
    var obj MyObject
    err := cur.Decode(&obj)
    //then display error if there's one        
}
```

And now I would like to end up with a JSON string containing all the documents my database returned in order to send it via HTTP.

Because, if use I `fmt.Println(obj)`I end up with something like this: `[{object1_name} {object2_name} ...]` which is, according to me, not a valid format that I can use for an API.

I know `json.Marshal(obj)` can actually encode to valid JSON and I can decode it with `os.Stdout.Write(obj)` but I didn't manage to store this valid string in a variable. How can I manage to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Golang [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for `json` package

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type ColorGroup struct {
        ID     int      `json:"id"`
        Name   string   `json:"name"`
        Colors []string `json:"colors"`
    }
    group := ColorGroup{
        ID:     1,
        Name:   "Reds",
        Colors: []string{"Crimson", "Red", "Ruby", "Maroon"},
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(group)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        str := string(b)
        fmt.Println("stringified json is:", str)

    }
}
```

```
Output
stringified json is: {"id":1,"name":"Reds","colors":["Crimson","Red","Ruby","Maroon"]}
```

The `json.Marshal` return two values - a `byte array` and `error`
If `error` is `nil` then you can obtain the string by converting `byte array` to `string` using
`str := string(b)`

Comment: You saved me hours of struggling. I'm new to Go and didn't know we could convert a byte array to a string. Thanks a lot!